# In Angular, is it bad practice to

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am making a custom directive and am trying to make it jQuery independent. In order to accomplish this without jQuery, the Scopes (parent and children) may have to interact directly. I certainly want to avoid "bad practices" as much as possible, so my question is this:

Is it bad practice to have a child scope directly call a function of the parent scope? If so, is there anyway to get the controller or element that governs a scope?

The reason this is necessary is that there may be multiple nested scopes of a directive. And I need to access a very particular one that is not necessarily the immediate parent of the current scope (though it is an ancestor).

**Edit: UseCase Elaboration**

The module contains two directives. Either of which may be nested in any number of parent directives. This child directive does require the parent directive accordingly, but in the case of nested parents, it only gets the controller of the most immediate parent.

The normal use of this will generally be:

```
<element parent-attr-dir="val">
    <element child-attr-dir="val"></element>
</element>
```

Notice that the values of the attributes must match. This is what determines which "ancestor" to attach to.

Advanced usage may resemble:

```
<element parent-attr-dir="value1">
    <element parent-attr-dir="value2">
        <element child-attr-dir="value1">Will run on top most ancestor</element>
        <element child-attr-dir="value2">Will run on immediate parent</element>
    </element>
    <element parent-attr-dir="value3">
        <element child-attr-dir="value3">Will run on immediate parent</element>
        <element child-attr-dir="value1">Will run on top most ancestor</element>
    </element>
    <element child-attr-dir="val">Will not run!!</element>
</element>
```

**Edit: Solution in Question**

This works, but need to know if its bad.

```
var _p = scope;
while (_p !== null) {
    if (_p.doSomething 
    &&  /* some other criteria. */ ) {
        _p.doSomething(scope);
    }
    _p = _p.$parent;
}
```

**Edit: Solution Using jQuery**

This works, but requires jQuery as jQLite does not have parent(selector), just parent().

```
$(element).parents('[attrname=value]').controller('moduleName').funcName()
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be for the children to require the parent directive and for the parent to optionally require the parent directive. Then a child calls the method of its immediate parent controller, passing along the criteria value; if the parent controller does not meet the criteria, it forwards the call to its own parent (if any), or nothing happens. A sketch of the solution:

```
app.directive("parentAttrDir", function() {
    return {
        require: ["?^parentAttrDir","parentAttrDir"],
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs,controllers) {
            var parentAttrDir = controllers[0],
                thisController = controllers[1],
                criterion = attrs.parentAttrDir;
            thisController.parent = parentAttrDir;
            thisController.criterion = criterion;
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.doSomething = function(data,criterion) {
                if( this.criterion === criterion ) {
                    // actually do something with the data
                }
                else if( this.parent != null ) {
                    return this.parent.doSomething(data,criterion);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive("childAttrDir", function() {
    return {
        require: "^parentAttrDir",
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs,parentAttrDir) {
            var criterion = attrs.childAttrDir;
            // EXAMPLE USAGE FROM CHILD
            scope.doSomeAction = function(data) {
                parentAttrDir.doSomething(data,criterion);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This will not suffice either. I have demonstrated why I need to occasionally "skip" parents. I have already proposed a solution. The question is whether or not that solution considered bad practice.

Comment: Please understand that your solution is quite handy, and I respect it and may even utilize it... but my question must be correctly addressed for this to be considered a valid answer.